# Using absolutely positioned element inside inline-block element in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

I keep getting weird results under Opera 10.60 trying to absolutely position block element inside inline-block element.

Sample code:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
div.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 100px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
div.block {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    border: 2px solid brown;
}
</style></head><body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block">(>O.o)></div>
  Quick brown block <a href="#">jumps</a> over relative div. 
</div>

</body></html>
```

Opera positions .block relative to the last inline element ( in this example) inside the same parent (.container), instead of positioning it relative to the parent.

Am I missing something, or is it just a bug, and I should find the other way around?

Comment: what's the idea behind display:block on a relatively positioned element?
EDIT: nevermind, I missed the question. Can't you create some sort of inline element (ie. span) to put the div in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your content in a div or something else, then it works.
http://jsbin.com/isuke3/edit

Answer (score 0):

Change
`position: relative;`
to
`position: absolute;`

and it will align itself correctly in the browsers. :)

Comment: It works, yes.

But on my website I have notifications which are made with the code similar to the sample, and I can't absolute position them around that easy without breaking markup.

Looks like I can use your advice and wrap each absolutely positioned .container with another, normally positioned block. It will double the code lenght, though :-)